# undefined reference to `main' in an online C compiler

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I am using an online compiler called onlinegdb ( https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler )

in which I wrote a simple program

```
#include <stdio.h>

double abs(double a) {

if(a < 0) a=-a;

return a;

}
```

but i am getting this as a result :

```
main.c:11:8: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘abs’

 double abs(double a) {

    ^~~

/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 11

/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 1 has invalid symbol index 12

/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 2 has invalid symbol index 2

/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 3 has invalid symbol index 2

....

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':

(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

where is the problem ? is it related to my computer or to the website or to the code ?

Comment: Every C program has to have a `main` function.  Otherwise the system doesn't know which function should begin the program.

Comment: `abs` is a standard C function and you should not use it. You need to have main function as well as it is program entry point https://onlinegdb.com/HkUfjuc8P I strongly advice a good C book.

Comment: every C program should have a ```main``` function. The first thing the compiler checks is the main function. you can also compile the program without using ```main``` function with this command ```gcc -ffreestanding -c program.c -o program.o``` but I won't recommend this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C, you should always have a `main()` function, because the computer always starts executing the code from the main function. Also, `abs` is a function defined in C, and so you cannot just name another function as `abs`. Instead, here's what you can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int a;
    printf("Enter the number to calculate the absolute value of: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    a = abs(a);
    printf("%d", a);
    return 0;
}
```

I have decided to start learning C after seeing this question, so my code might not be perfect, but I hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

`abs` is the name of a C function, it is a reserved keyword even if you do not include its header file `stdlib.h`.

If you really want to use it and you are using `gcc`, you can use the `fno-builtin` switch, but it is a really bad idea and such things are reserved for extremely advanced OS programmers.

Also every program needs a `main()` function.